# Merge Object Array into Array matched by property value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to merge in an array to an existing array by a key (id). Is there any easy way to do this?

For example:

```
people = [{id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}, {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe'}];
places = [{id: 1, state: 'CA'}, {id: 2, state: 'AK'}];

// expected output I want is
result = [{id: 1, name: 'John Doe', places: {id: 1, state: 'CA'}}, {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', places: {id: 2, state: 'AK}'}}];
```

How can I get places property id to map into people id so basically the ID's match up and they keys are carried in?

Comment: Since the `id` value in `places` is the same, why bother storing it in the result?

Comment: The people are fed from sqlite database in an Angular application and then looped and grouped.  Places are dynamic things in the form that are updated.  I need to carry these values and restore them using ngmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JS way to implement the scenario :

```js
const people = [{id: 1, name: 'John Doe'}, {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe'}];
const places = [{id: 1, state: 'CA'}, {id: 2, state: 'AK'}];

const result = people.map(ppl => {
   ppl.places = places.find(plc => plc.id === ppl.id)
   return ppl;
})
console.log(result)

// ES6 way 


let res = people.map(obj => {
    let data = places.find(item => item.id === obj.id);
    return {...obj, places: data}
});

console.log('ES6 way ......',res)
```